# play sound on mousehover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery menu and this is the code appears in the php file that calls the menu module and the default.php calls the jquery file of the menu which is hard to edit for me,

however, I would like to add a click sound when mouse over the nav menu li, kindly advice me how to do it, knowing that I can't edit the li a link in the index file to look like this 
 because it is generated in the jquery file, I only add menu and make the edits in joomla control panel.
Thank you very much.

Comment: please dont, sites that do such things are extremely annoying

Comment: It's my client's request , I'm out of it Dagon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) in your event handler. Something like this should work.

```
var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
$("nav li").mouseover(function() {
  audio.play();
}).mouseout(function() {
  audio.pause(); //optional to stop when not hovered anymore
});
```

Comment: Could `audio` be defined outside of `mouseover`, to prevent `new Audio` being called, resource requested, at each event?

Comment: the audio file plays on hover many times, how to make it play and stop, and work again on hover again ... Thank you

Comment: I added some code to pause the audio when no longer hovered

Comment: @dave the issue is still happening , the clip repeats itself, kindly check the url of my project

Comment: anyone knows how to make it stop looping ?

Comment: @EhabMamdouhIsmaiel when I test this here I don't get the problem with repeating. I suggest opening a new question asking about the repeating audio.